# EU refugee quota proposal

Tags: immigration, refugees

I would like to read the proposal of the EU refugee quota system. Could someone tell me, where to find it? I did not find anything official on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [first search result on Google](http://eumigrationlawblog.eu/refugee-quotas-allowing-eu-member-states-to-choose-between-physical-and-financial-solidarity/) for "proposal of the EU refugee quota system" includes a [link to the official proposal](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/european-agenda-migration/proposal-implementation-package/docs/proposal_for_regulation_of_ep_and_council_establishing_a_crisis_relocation_mechanism_en.pdf), interprets it in plain English and discusses its implications.